# How to pass two objects in WCF Web Reference Method

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest, web-services

I am have been coding a web reference [Web service], I am newbie in web references, and I need to pass to objects which are in a different classes to a method. This is my code

```
[OperationContract]
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "/GetData/GetCreditScore")]
    DataAccess.PersonRes GetCreditScore(DataAccess.Person Person, DataAccess.Address Address);
```

**La operación 'GetCreditScore' del contrato 'IWelcomeWCFService' utiliza GET, pero también tiene los parámetros del cuerpo 'Person'. Las operaciones GET no pueden tener cuerpo. Convierta el parámetro 'Person' en un parámetro UriTemplate, o bien pase de WebGetAttribute a WebInvokeAttribute.**

The main method is the following:

```
#region Get Credit Score With TransUnion
    public DataAccess.PersonRes GetCreditScore(DataAccess.Person Person, DataAccess.Address Address)
    {
        DataAccess.PersonRes Res = new DataAccess.PersonRes();
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        string pfxPath = @"C:\Users\RodolfoPC\Desktop\VOLTELE3_SHA2.p12";
        X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2(File.ReadAllBytes(pfxPath), "Volt2018");
        SignXmlDocumentWithCer(doc, cert);
        using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
        {
            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
            String result = "";
            string strPost = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><creditBureau xmlns=\"http://www.transunion.com/namespace\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xsi:schemaLocation=\"http://www.transunion.com/namespace\"><version>2.21</version><document>request</document><transactionControl><userRefNumber /><subscriber><industryCode>U</industryCode><memberCode>2495965</memberCode><inquirySubscriberPrefixCode>0622</inquirySubscriberPrefixCode><password>VTWW</password></subscriber><options><processingEnvironment>standardTest</processingEnvironment><country>us</country><language>en</language></options></transactionControl><product><code>08000</code><subject><number>1</number><subjectRecord><indicative><name><person><first>" + Person.Name + "</first><middle>L</middle><last>" + Person.LastName + "</last></person></name><address><status>current</status><street><number>" + Address.Number + "</number><name>" + Address.Name + "</name></street><location><city>" + Address.City + "</city><state>" + Address.State + "</state><zipCode>" + Address.Zip + "</zipCode></location></address><socialSecurity><number>" + Person.SSN + "</number></socialSecurity></indicative></subjectRecord></subject><responseInstructions><returnErrorText>true</returnErrorText><document /></responseInstructions></product></creditBureau>";
            StreamWriter myWriter = null;
            HttpWebRequest objRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://netaccess-test.transunion.com/");
            objRequest.Method = "POST";
            objRequest.ContentLength = strPost.Length;
            objRequest.ContentType = "text/xml";
            objRequest.ClientCertificates.Add(new X509Certificate2(@"C:\Users\RodolfoPC\Desktop\VOLTELE3_SHA2.p12", "********"));
            try
            {
                myWriter = new StreamWriter(objRequest.GetRequestStream());
                myWriter.Write(strPost);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string err = ex.ToString();
            }
            finally
            {
                myWriter.Close();
            }
            HttpWebResponse objResponse = (HttpWebResponse)objRequest.GetResponse();
            using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(new StreamReader(objResponse.GetResponseStream())))
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    if (reader.ReadToDescendant("results"))
                    {
                        reader.Read();//this moves reader to next node which is text 
                        result = reader.Value; //this might give value than 
                        Res.Response = true;
                        Res.SocialSecurityScore = result.ToString();
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Res.Response = false;
                        Res.SocialSecurityScore = "Your credit score might not be available. Please contact support";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        #region Returns the results from Operations
        return Res;//This returns 
        #endregion
    }
    #endregion
```

Can somebody help me about this issue?

Comment: 500 is always a mystery.  It's like the server is telling you "it's broken, and I won't tell you why! Tough luck!"  We should all strive to provide better error messages than that.

Comment: However it is weird, because I am using SOAPui to test the web services and the system works perfectly. With no issues. Is there any way I can import SSL certificate into the asp.net c# app?

Comment: The webpage says following : The digital certificate is invalid. Please ensure you have the correct digital certificate or download a new digital certificate, and then resubmit the transactions. if the situation persists, notify the TransUnion Service Desk at 800-813-5604.

Comment: The client and server cannot communicate common algorithm.

Comment: What does it mean? I've tried with SOAPui and it works perfectly but my app